# Understanding these machine learning curves?

Tags: machine-learning, model, loss, unet-neural-network

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkorJ.png)
#machine_learning

My model has 3 images for the testing and I got these curves as result, I do not know how to explain these curves in the report

Comment: So if I understand correctly, your validation set consists of 3 images. How large is your training set? The curves look like overfitting, meaning your training set is too small.

Answer (score 0):

Your model might be overfitting, as your train accuracy is always(in all epochs) higher than your validation accuracy. But it depends more or less on your data points. For your report, better include your methods to avoid overfitting, as for this case, why you choose specific model can be more reasonable.